# Пару вопросов к задаче на оператор switch()

Tags: c++, switch

Нужно написать программу перевода введенного символа шестнадцатеричной системы счисления в восьмеричную систему. Получилось следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char x;
        cout << "x = ";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x)
        {
        case 0:cout <<"0"; break;
        case 1:cout <<"1"; break;
        case 2:cout <<"2"; break;
        case 3:cout << "3"; break;
        case 4:cout << "4"; break;
        case 5:cout << "5"; break;
        case 6:cout << "6"; break;
        case 7:cout << "7"; break;
        case 8:cout << "10"; break;
        case 9:cout << "11"; break;
        case 'A':cout << "12"; break;
        case 'B':cout << "13"; break;
        case 'C':cout << "14"; break;
        case 'D':cout << "15"; break;
        case 'E':cout << "16"; break;
        case 'F':cout << "17"; break;
        default: cout << "Error\n";
        };
    }
```

Отсюда два вопроса:

1. Как сделать ввод сразу нескольких чисел/букв т.к программа работает только при одном введенном символе
2. Как сделать так, что бы в консоль вводились, например, только заглавные буквы (A-F), что бы не писать кейс и для заглавных и для маленьких букв, или как это можно реализовать по другому.

Comment: 1. Вводите в цикле `while (cin >> x) { ... }`  2. Посмотрите таблицу ascii кодов. Коды больших и маленьких букв отличаются на  32

Comment: Вообще если покопаться то в std есть функции конверсии шестнадцатеричных чисел

Comment: циклом считывайте по одной букве. Запоминайте четвёртый бит (самый главный). И дальше совмещайте побитно. Сначала сами напишите, потом подправим.

Answer (score 4):

Собственно вся програмка будет составлять пару строк с использованием возможностей стандартной библиотеки с++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
  int num;
  std::cin >> std::hex >> num;
  std::cout << std::oct << num;
  return 0;
}
```

Пример ввода-вывода

```
>> 10
<< 20
```